# Python: Retrieve original url from a url fileobject

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I need to retrieve the original url which was passed to the filehandler, are there some methods for it. I don't want to use url. Till now not able to find any.

```
filehandler =  urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the location:

```
print filehandler.url
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this is the `url` attribute not the `url` argument.

Comment: Perfect it worked, so intutive,  had read whole of urllib2 docs sicne past hour  but couldn't find it. Where is this even described? Didn't ask here for long since people would downvote a noob question. thx

Comment: @garg10may: the documentation does have `response.geturl()`; not all responses have a `.url` attribute.

Comment: If you're working in IDLE, there is an auto-complete that shows that attributes by clicking control and space. If not, use `dir(filehandler)` to list them.